# react native get component height when componentdidmount

Tags: react-native

I use 0.21.0 react native, 
I have one custom component.

for animated, I find solution to get height.
width is get using Dimension. but height is not same.

How do I get height of my component?

Comment: Check out `onLayout`. We could probably be more helpful with code to look at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Chris Geirman pointed out in the comment, you can use `onLayout` for this. Here an example to get the height of this component:

```
var CustomComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { componentHeight: 0 };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View onLayout={this._onLayoutEvent}>
        <Text>This is my Custom Component</Text>
      </View>
    );
  },

  _onLayoutEvent: function(event) {
    this.setState({componentHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height});
  }
});
```

Now you have access to the height of the component as `this.state.componentHeight`.

Comment: thank you @Andru,  I need to set height with animated value.
`<View onLayout={this._onLayoutEvent} style={{height: this.state.componentHeight}}`

Comment: onLayout() doesn't get fired every time. I think it may be a bug in react native.